How do I fix the error "The project could not be built due to "core does not exist""
I am using visual studios with jdk 17 and libgdx implementation. I ran into this issue awhile ago and it is pretty annoying as I can run my code fine with no issues, I just cannot use autofill or see errors underlined. I am using github to work on this across devices, and I did not originally have this issue when I first built my script. After a few commits, one device does not have this issue but 2 do. I am using libgdx for desktop development aswell.

This is my directory hierarchy if it helps.
core build.gradle:
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-core"

desktop build.gradle:
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["../assets"]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.mygdx.game.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../assets")

import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

tasks.register('run', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn classes
    mainClass = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true

    if (OperatingSystem.current() == OperatingSystem.MAC_OS) {
        // Required to run on macOS
        jvmArgs += "-XstartOnFirstThread"
    }
}

tasks.register('debug', JavaExec) {
    dependsOn classes
    mainClass = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}

tasks.register('dist', Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar
}


dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-desktop"

Main build.gradle:
buildscript {
    

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Mario"
        gdxVersion = '1.12.1'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.20'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.4'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
        gdxControllersVersion = '2.2.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        
    }
}

settings.gradle:
include 'desktop', 'core'

Let me know if any more information needs to be provided!

Figured out the issue, for some reason renaming core and desktop to random things and then remaining them back to their originals made the project work again.
